# Why GROUPBY doesn't work?

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas

I don't know why but pandas groupby doesn't work in this case whereas I used it well in other scripts.

All lines are still there after it.

This is my code:

```
all_points['WKT'] = all_points['geometry'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
all_points = all_points.drop(['geometry'], axis=1)
grouped_all_points = all_points.groupby('WKT')
```

Extract of "all_points":

```
                                          geometry
0     POINT (-86241.02513844217 5631462.009346757)
1     POINT (-86239.44367486052 5631461.385669805)
2     POINT (-86239.04011918581 5631462.408969769)
3     POINT (-86240.62158276746 5631463.032646721)
4     POINT (-86241.02513844217 5631462.009346757)
5     POINT (-86239.44367486052 5631461.385669805)
6     POINT (-86237.86221127887 5631460.761992853)
7     POINT (-86237.45865560416 5631461.785292817)
8     POINT (-86239.04011918581 5631462.408969769)
9     POINT (-86239.44367486052 5631461.385669805)
10    POINT (-86237.86221127887 5631460.761992853)
```

Comment: Can you specify what "doesn't work" ? What do you further do with `grouped_all_points` ?

Comment: After groupby (3rd line) when I print grouped_all_points, points who are identical should be group in a unique line and it isn't the case. For example n°0 and 4, 1 and 4...

Comment: I think you are not printing `grouped_all_points` then, which is a `GroupBy` object. You still need to call a method on that to see the actual groups, like `all_points.groupby('WKT').first()`

Comment: Oh well yes ! If we don't tell how it must group by, it can't work... Thank you.